# backup GPT table is corrupt. Running fdisk

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

I went to check my disk with fdisk -l and came up with one that says the `The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.`

I'm not sure which disk it is referring to but I suspect it may be my bootable USB which is 16GB.

What should I do about this?

here is the terminal output.

````
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for amnesia: 
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier:

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       206848 522741759 522534912 249.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.9 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048 16779263 16777216    8G EFI System
/dev/sdb2  16783360 31266782 14483423  6.9G Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/loop0: 1.1 GiB, 1181437952 bytes, 2307496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 75.7 MiB, 79384576 bytes, 155048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/TailsData_unlocked: 6.9 GiB, 7413415424 bytes, 14479327 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1536002047 1536000000 732.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc2  1536002048 3072002047 1536000000 732.4G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sdc3  3072002048 3906758655  834756608   398G Linux filesystem
amnesia@amnesia:~$```
````

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Invoke `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` separately to see beyond any doubt which drive the message refers to. [Edit] the question if appropriate. Was your bootable USB created by `dd`-ing an image file to it? Or by any equivalent way that just writes some generic image to the device?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you had run `fdisk -l` — that is, w/o specifying the device, — it apparently scanned all the devices it found.

When it scanned `/dev/sda`, it found two facts about it (amongh other things):

- It uses the partition table in the so-called GPT format (another alternative on (older) x86 hardware is so-caller MBR).
- It found that the backup copy of the GPT partition table is corrupt but the primary is OK.

It that went forward and read the primary copy and output the data from it. Then it did so for the other storage devices.

> What should I do about this?

This is not exactly easy to answer.

An obvious, glib, response is to restore the backup copy and call it a day. [Here's how](https://askubuntu.com/a/697315).

But the fact it's corrupt may be a signal that the drive's hardware is failing. And it may be not.

I'd do the following.

1. Back all the data up from that drive somewhere
   using the usual file copy, `tar` or whatever suits you best.
2. Back its partition data up:

   ```
   # sfdisk --dump /dev/sda > /path/to/sda.part
   ```
3. Run hardware stressing test on the device;
   the venerable `badblocks` may do it:

   ```
   # badblocks -s -w -p N /dev/sda
   ```

   (You may also add `-v` for it do be extra chatty, though `-s` is usually sufficient.)

   Notice the `-w` — *"destructive* read/write test", — and `-p N` which sets the number of passes to `N`. Pick that number to be at least, I dunno, 4.

   > Let me repeat: running the tests in the `-w` mode will destroy all the data on the drive. But in return, this mode stresses the most it can from the drive.
4. After `badblocks` completes (it may take a while—especially with large `N`), look for what it reported.

   If it reported failures, your drive should be considered dead and thrown away or exchanged if it's still covered by its warranty.
5. If `badblocks` said there's nothing wrong with the drive, run `smartctl` from the `smartmontools` package:

   ```
   # smartctl --all /dev/sda
   ```

   and then pay close attention to a number of things:

   - An error log; in a really fit drive it must be empty.
   - SMART variables dealing with bad blocks: `Reallocated_Event_Count`, `Current_Pending_Sector`, `Offline_Uncorrectable`. These variables mean, in order: the number of sectors (blocks) remapped, the number of blocks currently considered bad and being tested by the drive's firmware, the number of sectors found by the drive's firmware to be bad but which cannot be remapped since the table of free sectors for remapping was exhausted by the previous bad blocks.

   (It may be a good idea to look up on SMART in general.)

   If you see anything wrong around those reading, it's best to not rely on the drive.
6. After all, if all is well, you could claim with certain degree of confidence that the corruption of the backup GPT was due to some unknown factors (aliens, illuminati etc) and proceed with restoring the drive:

   1. Get back the partition table:

      # sfdisk /dev/sda < /path/to/sda.part
   2. Make sure the OS sees the new partitions:

      # blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sda
   3. Recreate the filesystems on the restored partitions using whatever tooling you prefer (looks the both partitions are exFAT).
   4. Restore the files.